# Is it possible to use regex to match strings that contain only words from a set list

Tags: regex

I would like to match strings that contain only words from a set list.

If I have the string "testing something" I want to match that string using "testing random list of words something" but not match the string if I use "testing random".

Examples:-

"blue green" must be matched using following list "green yellow blue"

"blue green" must not be matched using following list "green yellow purple"

"five seven" must be matched using following list "two seven six five"

"five seven" must not be matched using following list "two six five"

I tried using regex lookaheads but the regex matches only strings that contain all the words in the list. That regex is:-

`^(?=.*\btesting\b)(?=.*\brandom\b)(?=.*\bsomething\b).+`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think regular expression might be overkill for something like this, when you can just iterate your set list and match it against your string yourself

Comment: Maybe gives some examples of strings that should match and strings that should not

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Unfortunately I'm communication with an API that accepts regex or direct string match.

Comment: @rghome I've added some more examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want the whole string to match a sequence of items, where each item must be a word from the set. To match strings that contain words only from the set {testing, random, something}, the corresponding (Perl-like) regex would be

```
/^((testing|random|something)\b\s*)*$/
```

That is, the whole string must match zero-or-more sequences of a permissible word followed by a word boundary and possibly some whitespace.

Demo perl script:

```
my @words=qw/only words from this list/;

my $pattern='^(('.join('|',@words).')\b\s*)*$';
print /$pattern/?"ok\n":"fail\n" while <>;
```

Demo output:

```
$ perl wlregex.pl << _eod
> words list only
> words banana only
> _eod
ok
fail
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great for me: `/^((test|testing|tester|test1)\b\s*)*$/i` matches "test" but not "test2" which was incorrectly matching without the extra `^( ... )\b\s*)*$` surrounding the pipe delimited strings. You will need to escape the \ when creating the regex in javascript with: `new RegExp(\`^((${stringArray.join("|")})\\b\\s*)*$\`, "i");`